# Find All Pairs Of Target Sum

Tags: kdb

Can you please help on solution in kdb to find all pairs of target sum.
I have find the solution in java using multiple containers but not able to solve in vector programming.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FindAllPairsOfTargetSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1 };
        FindAllPairsOfTargetSum.findPairs(arr,10);
    }

    public static void findPairs(int arr[], int sum){
        int[][] arrays =new int[10][] ;
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        int pairsarr[][] = new int[arr.length][arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(map.containsKey(sum - arr[i])){
                System.out.println(" Pair is found : ("+arr[map.get(sum-arr[i])]+": "+(arr[i])+" )");
            }else{
                map.put(arr[i], i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:Pair is found : (8: 2 )
Pair is found : (7: 3 )

Comment: Can you add details fo what you have tried so far? This will help you get answers to push you in the right direction. Currently this question reads as "do my homework" as you have not demonstrated you have tried to find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q)x:8 7 2 5 3 1

q)pairs where 10=sum each pairs:raze {{first[y _ x],/: (y+1) _ x}[x] each y}[x;til count x]
8 2
7 3
```

Breaking it down: uses the `til count x` idiom to pass in list indices (along with the list) to the lambda `{{first[y _ x],/: (y+1) _ x}[x] each y}`, which gives:

```
(8 7;8 2;8 5;8 3;8 1)
(7 2;7 5;7 3;7 1)
(2 5;2 3;2 1)
(5 3;5 1)
,3 1
()
```

`raze`-ing this result gives

```
(8 7;8 2;8 5;8 3;8 1;7 2;7 5;7 3;7 1;2 5;2 3;2 1;5 3;5 1;3 1)
```

And then we find the elements where the sum of each pair is 10.
Also worth looking at the `_` drop operator: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/drop/ and for similar problems: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cross/

Comment: Thank you James for the example.  I tried with example as java program but not able to get solve in kdb. You helped to in think vector programming solution.